# How to hear the mic from the CLI?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, microphone

My various microphones work fine, and I can record myself with various applications, but I can't hear myself talking while recording. All I need is some application that will play the mic without a lot of fuss, just to hear my own voice.

I'm wondering if there's a CLI solution to my question, for example using mplayer or some other simple command, perhaps piping the output of the mic to the headphones? I'm using pulseaudio, but I would accept any solution, as long as I can hear myself through my headphones, aka the "built-in audio analog stereo" device.

I can test my webcam like `mplayer tv://` But is there an equivalent for microphones, like hypothetically `mplayer mic://` obviously doesn't work. This is not necessarily an mplayer question, any software solution will be accepted, the simpler the better.

Comment: `I can't hear myself talking while recording` ... that is intentional ...it prevents an unpleasant sonic event caused by feedback

Comment: @jsotola Yes that is a good reason for the default, however the default is not what I'm asking about. But since you mentioned it, I own Sony digital audio recorder and it plays the audio from the mic while recording--which is useful in a lot of situations.

Comment: There's lots of solutions on different levels, e.g. Pulseaudio `module-loopback`, or `alsamixer` or `amixer` to enable hardware loopback (if your codec supports that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arecord -f cd - | aplay -`

Should do it but it may lead to quite nasty consequences if you're not using headphones.

Also read this topic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/123798/how-to-hear-my-voice-in-speakers-with-a-mic

Comment: This works, but I'm going to experiment with it and figure out the parameters before acecpting the answer. Ideally there would be less delay (or maybe my PC is slow haha.)